# PHP syntax differences from MySQL to SQL Server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have been working on a Login/Register System, I had it all set up and working perfectly in MySQL, but I need to run it from SQL SERVER 2008, so I have changed the connection over and its all working apart from 1 bit, when the user click a verification link i the email it isn't verifying the user so I am thinking that some of the syntax doesn't work with PHP7 and SQL server.

This is the code:

```
$stmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT userID,userStatus FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uID AND tokenCode=:code LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute(array(":uID"=>$id,":code"=>$code));
$row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
some code...}
else{ error message...}
```

Its skipping the if statement and just giving me the error message from the else.

Is there something obviously wrong that i am not seeing?

Any help would be appreciated at this point!!

Thanks.

EDIT:

This is the code form the IF statement if it helps...

```
if($row['userStatus']==$statusN)
    {
        $stmt = $user->runQuery("UPDATE po_users SET userStatus=:status WHERE userID=:uID");
        $stmt->bindparam(":status",$statusY);
        $stmt->bindparam(":uID",$id);
        $stmt->execute();   

        $msg = "
               <div class='alert alert-success'>
               <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
                  <strong>WoW !</strong>  Your Account is Now Activated : <a href='index.php'>Login here</a>
               </div>
               ";   
    }
    else
    {
        $msg = "
               <div class='alert alert-error'>
               <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
                  <strong>sorry !</strong>  Your Account is allready Activated : <a href='index.php'>Login here</a>
               </div>
               ";
    }
```

Comment: What you obviously not see is a manual for `rowCount`

Comment: SQL SERVER does not have `LIMIT`, use `SELECT TOP` instead

Comment: Since you fetched, just `count($row)` maybe.

Comment: Tried SELECT TOP Vitalii, still not working :(

Comment: Can you please show us what SQL error do you have?

Comment: [Fri Nov 04 14:42:51.157468 2016] [:error] [pid 2800:tid 500] [client 10.11.1.78:58757] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function sqlsrv_num_rows() on boolean in C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\Login\\verify.php:21\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\Login\\verify.php on line 21

This is the error form my apache log

Comment: when your userID is unique, than you can just skip the whole LIMIT / TOP thing. you'll only receive 1 record nevertheless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQl Server does not have LIMIT. Limit use with mysql. Instead of Limit use top.

Refer:http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

```
SELECT TOP 1 userID,userStatus FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uID AND tokenCode=:code
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the `TOP 1`.  You may be missing the 1.

```
SELECT TOP 1 userID, userStatus 
FROM tbl_users 
WHERE userID=:uID AND tokenCode=:code
```

Answer (score 0):

So this error says that you try to call a member function on a boolean value

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function sqlsrv_num_rows() on boolean

So instead of :

```
$stmt->execute(array(":uID"=>$id,":code"=>$code));
$row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){...
```

try this:

```
$result = $stmt->execute(array(":uID"=>$id,":code"=>$code));
if($result->rowCount() > 0){
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help but after I made the changes you suggested, i get a new error before i get the same boolean error:
[Mon Nov 07 08:37:13.165015 2016] [:error] [pid 2884:tid 968] [client 10.11.1.78:52544] PHP Warning:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\Login\\signup.php on line 21, referer: http://10.11.1.224/Login/signup.php

Comment: This is the line its complaining about:
if($result->rowCount() > 0){